# $Fix(Gal(E/F))=F$ if $E$ is the algebraic closure of $F$ and separable over $F$.

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $E$ be an algebraic closure of $F$ and assume that $E$ is separable over $F$. What I want to show that $$
Fix(Gal(E/F))=F.
$$
By Fundamental Theorem of Galois Theory, we know that $Fix(Gal(E/F))=F$ if $E$ is Galois over $F$.

My question: Can I show using the given assumptions that $E$ is a Galois extension of $F$?.

Comment: Typically $E/F$ is infinite. How much infinite Galois theory do you know? If enough, then this result is pretty much a part of it. Otherwise you may need things like a Zorn's Lemon argument showing that any $F$-automorphism of a finite extension of $F$ can be extended to one of $E$, reducing this claim to the "standard" finite Galois theory.

Comment: @JyrkiLahtonen I didn't know Zorn had a lemon ^^ Presumably, you meant "lemma".

Comment: @Arthur Just one of the silly grade school style jokes that were circulating when I was in grad school. *What's yellow and maximal?* *What's green and commutative?*